# Shadows in tableview keep stacking (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I currently have a list of 70 questions in a tableview. Once a question is solved, the table is updated and shows a checkmark (all works OK).

The issue I am having is with the shadow that I add to each of my cells in the tableview. For some reason they keep stacking when scrolling up and down. Also when putting the device in landscape, the new CGRect is drawn, but the old one is still there (also overlap).

The code:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell:QuestionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! QuestionCell
let bgColorView = UIView()
        bgColorView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, (tableView.frame.width)-10, (cell.frame.height)-10)
        bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView

        let myBackView=UIView(frame:cell.frame)
        myBackView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, (tableView.frame.width)-10, (cell.frame.height)-10)
        myBackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
        myBackView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        myBackView.clipsToBounds = false
        myBackView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        myBackView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1)
        myBackView.layer.shadowRadius = 2
        myBackView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4;
        let test:CGRect = myBackView.layer.bounds
        myBackView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: test).CGPath
        cell.addSubview(myBackView)
        cell.sendSubviewToBack(myBackView)



        if (question.showAfter == "true") {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
            //give header of correct question blue color
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightTextColor()
            cell.headerQuestion.textColor = UIColor(red:0.01, green:0.53, blue:0.82, alpha:1.0)
            }
        else
        {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                cell.headerQuestion.textColor = UIColor(red:0.38, green:0.49, blue:0.55, alpha:1.0)
        }
        return cell

}
```

[image: overlapping of the shadows at rotating (or scrolling up/down)]

I have already tried the following (it was a solution from someone on an objective-C topic):

```
let tag = 120 
if (cell.tag != 120) {
//the above code here
cell.tag = tag 
}
```

This solves the shadow issue, BUT when I turn the device to landscape mode it does not redraw.
Any ideas? All are welcome

Comment: Cells are reused, so you need to ensure that the shadow and check ark are removed/added if necessary.  Store the shadowview as a property of your cell and remove it if the question hasn't been answered, add it if it has - don't add again it if the property isn't nil. Same thing with setting the accessory. How do you know whether a question is solved or not?

Comment: I know if a question is solved by checking the database (code wasn't added here, but it's part of the question.showAfter = true.

Comment: Ok, so basically if showAfter==true the question should be displayed with check mark/shadow?

Comment: I want the shadow shown the whole time on my rectangle, but ShahiM seems to have found the solution for me ^^ thanks anyway for your help

Comment: Paul is right, cells are frequently reused from a queue of old cells instead of creating new ones all the time(ever wondered why its called deque?)... When it us reused, the tableview has no way of knowing what subviews are present inside the cell, so it is up to you to keep track of that(say, through a property in your cell)...

Comment: If you always want the shadow why not simply add it in your custom cell's `initWithStyle:reuseidzntifier` function? Or at the very least add an optional property to hold the reference to the shadow and check that for nil - the view tag hack is just icky.

Comment: I'm going to have to try and do something like that, because with the solution of ShaniM, my tableview doesn't redraw itself after turning, which I still want. Not sure on how to do all of this on the prototype cell though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your adding a new shadow every time a cell is reused. You should only add the shadow once at creation time.

Make a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and do your common customizations (background color, shadow) there. Then register your class with the tableview. Only do stuff that's different per cell in `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Comment: Thanks, and do I just put it in the viewdidload of the subclass (or in what method of the subclass?).

Comment: `UITableViewCells` and `UIViews` don't have `viewDidLoad`. You can put it in your override of  `init(style style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier reuseIdentifier: String?)` or `awakeFromNib` if you're using a xib file.

Comment: thanks a lot, at first I didn't understand where you wanted to go with it, but once I did, it all seems so logical :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
if(cell.viewWithTag(120)==nil)
{
  let myBackView=UIView(frame:cell.frame)
  myBackView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, (tableView.frame.width)-10, (cell.frame.height)-10)
  myBackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
  myBackView.layer.masksToBounds = false
  myBackView.clipsToBounds = false
  myBackView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
  myBackView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1)
  myBackView.layer.shadowRadius = 2
  myBackView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
  let test:CGRect = myBackView.layer.bounds
  myBackView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: test).CGPath

  myBackView.tag = 120;

  cell.addSubview(myBackView)
}
  cell.sendSubviewToBack(myBackView)
```

Comment: only issue is that nothing is redrawn after you rotate your device, making it look bad when in landscape mode. Guess I'll have to find a different solution